# Handling 'Undefined array key' warnings in PHP8

Tags: php, migration, php-8

Due to PHP8 escalating Undefined array key notices to warnings I have a problem with error logs being flooded due to our legacy code being written in a way that relied on PHP's implicit truthy/falsy-ness.

E.g.

```
if ($_POST['submit']) { ... } else { ... }
<input value="<?=$this_page['id']?>"> # in a shared add/edit form
```

Previously I was happy to suppress E_NOTICE, I'm not prepared to do this with E_WARNING.

I'm aware that the best solution would be refactoring code to make use of wrapper/abstraction classes to interact with superglobals and use object based models for database objects. Unfortunately, I have more than 100+ legacy applications to make PHP8 compliant inside of 6 months, therefore major refactoring isn't within scope.

I've tried using ArrayObject, which can solve some problems by overloading the offsetGet/Set, but this breaks compatibility with array_* functions and creates potential issues with third-party packages.

I'm wondering if anyone has developed a workaround for this yet, or has any ideas around a more drop in replacement. I'm open to pretty much any ideas other than major refactoring or shutting the projects down! Search/replace, project specific config, server level config, polyfills, I'm there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to do some find-and-replace, there are a few constructs which guarantee the same behaviour but without the Warning.

The most universal is [the `??` null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), which lets you convert an unset array key into an explicit null:

```php
if ($_POST['submit']??null) { ... } else { ... }
<input value="<?=$this_page['id']??null?>">
```

More logically, the default in an echo statement is an empty string:

```php
<input value="<?=$this_page['id']??''?>">
```

The logical default in an if statement is a boolean false, but perhaps more readable is [the `empty` pseudo-function](https://www.php.net/empty):

```php
if (! empty($_POST['submit'])) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Can't fault the answer and this is one of the more technically correct possibilities. I just _don't_ like the extra bloat it adds to code/readability.

Comment: Would also add that the `isset` function is an option as the logical opposite of `empty`

Comment: @scoota269 isset and !empty are not quite equivalent: isset would return true for an empty string or 0, which would be false in the existing code or with !empty